# Why does Thread FileDate give an error message?

Tags: list-manipulation, files-and-directories

I tried for example

```
Thread[FileDate[FileNames["new*", "h:\\temp\\", 1]]]
```

It gives

> FileDate::fstr: File specification
>   {h:\temp\NEWEA7D.tmp,h:\temp\NEWEA7E.tmp,h:\temp\NEWEAAE.tmp} is not a
>   string of one or more characters. >>

but still gives the right answer

```
Out[13]= {{2013, 11, 18, 23, 14, 32.}, {2013, 11, 18, 23, 14, 
  32.}, {2013, 11, 18, 23, 14, 32.}}
```

Why is there a error message? How to avoid it?

Comment: `FileDate` evaluates before `Thread` has a chance to perform its action. There are a few ways to fix this, the simplest one is probably this: `Block[{FileDate},your-code]`.

Comment: I seem to remember similar question discussed before, but could not find it, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a consequence of the semantics of `Thread`, which does not hold its arguments. This issue has been discussed many times in various Mathematica - related resources. For the case at hand, and also generally, there are several ways to avoid this issue.

The simplest solution would be to just avoid `Thread` here and use `Map` instead:

```
Map[FileDate, FileNames["*.nb", {"~/Documents"}, 1]]
```

If you insist on using `Thread`, then, basically, we want to prevent `FileDate` from evaluating before it gets appropriately threaded. In this case, this is made more complicated because we should still evaluate the inner code. One way to do this is this (I am using a slightly different code as an example):

```
With[{fnames = FileNames["*.nb", {"~/Documents"}, 1]},
   Thread[Unevaluated[FileDate[fnames]]]
]
```

in this case, we use `With` to inject the piece of evaluated code, and `Unevaluated` to prevent `FileDate` from evaluating before it is threaded.

One other way to do this is to use the `Block` trick, to make `FileDate` temporarily inert:

```
Block[{FileDate}, Thread[FileDate[FileNames["*.nb", {"~/Documents"}, 1]]]]
```

There are other ways to resolve this, of course.

Comment: Thank you Leonid Shifrin! I found `SetAttribute[FileDate,Listable] works, but I seems to remember a post say setattribute to Listable is not a good way, I can't find the post now, do you know that post?

Comment: What is more. If you could refine this line of code, I will be appreciate. `Part[#, Flatten@Position[AbsoluteTime /@Thread@FileDate[#],Max[AbsoluteTime /@Thread@FileDate[#]]]] &@FileNames["math*"]`. This line of code intends to find the newest created file which has a name contained "math". I just can't eliminate the duplicate in my code, because it will involve pure function in pure function.

Comment: @matheorem Was glad to help. Re - post: there was one I did on `Listable` recently, but that was about efficiency. There is another reason to advise against this, and this is that `FileDate` is a built-in function. Therefore, you never know what you might break by making such modifications. It may be used internally, where people assumed that it is not `Listable`, for example.

Comment: @matheorem Try this (untested): `With[{fdabs = AbsoluteTime /@ Thread@FileDate[#]},Part[#, Flatten@Position[fdabs, Max[fdabs]]]]& @ FileNames["math*"]`.

Comment: Position[fdabs, Max[fdabs]]] likes `Fold` but not the Fold way :)

Comment: So defining a local variable is inevitable? may be some tricky method?

Comment: @matheorem May be not inevitable (look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/composition-of-functions-using-slots/35329#35329) for some ideas), but IMO rather natural.