# Defining a sequence slot programmatically

Tags: functional-style, pure-function, sequence

This question is related to:

[Composition of functions using slots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/composition-of-functions-using-slots)

[`Slot` (#) interfering with evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45142/slot-interfering-with-evaluation)

Consider a toy example:

```
 list1 = { {a1, b1, c1, d1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2}, {a3, b3, c3, d3} };
```

I’d like to take elements from the list as follows example:

```
{#1, #2}@@@ list1
```

But I’d like to able to define #1, #2 programmatically.

I tried:

```
n=1;
{Slot@Evaluate[n], Slot@Evaluate[n + 1]} & @@@ list1
```

But it gives me an error…

Answers appreciated.**Even better if the answer uses the # notation rather than the Slot function.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to insert values into held expressions:

```
With[{n=1,m=2},
  {Slot[n], Slot[m]} & @@@ list1
]
```

> {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}}

If you're so inclined, you can do a nested `With`:

```
With[{n = 1},
 With[{m = n + 1},
  {Slot[n], Slot[m]} & @@@ list1
 ]
]
```

Or with [Leonid's exceedingly nice `LetL`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/5485):

```
LetL[{n = 1, m = n + 1},
  {Slot[n], Slot[m]} & @@@ list1
]
```

Comment: oh. I was too late!

Comment: @acl Sorry, I cheated a bit by first posting half of my answer. Too bad you removed yours, as I wasn't aware that `With[{n = n},...]` was also allowed.

Comment: +1. You can also use `Where` in V10 see my answer.

Comment: That's a very useful trick. Why don't you add it to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice function in the `GeneralUtilities` package included in **Version 10** called `Where`. You can use this as:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Where[n = 1, m = n + 1, {Slot[n], Slot[m]} & @@@ list1]
```

Gives:

```
{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}}
```

Comment: +1 Nice to hear indeed. I wonder if this is in fact based upon @LeonidShifrin's `LetL`.

Comment: @TeakeNutma I wonder too. I just hope it is added as an internal function in a future release as I always use such functionality.

Comment: Thanks… I haven’t upgraded to MMA 10… but this is great….

Comment: @TeakeNutma AFAIK its not. `LetL` also supports shared local variables in definitions, as well as macro-expands at definition time, which makes it zero overhead w.r.t. manually-written nested `With` in function definitions (these are related). Again AFAIK, `Where` does not have this functionality.

Comment: `Where` seems to have a definition intended to catch things like `Where[{x,y}={2, 3}, f[x,y]]` that they added last and is never tried. To fix it, use `DownValues[Where] = RotateRight@DownValues@Where`