# How do I map a function onto the result of an expression that already has a pure function as an argument

Tags: function-construction

I admit that I have only a basic understanding of the way Mathematica handles pure functions - enough to be dangerous, unfortunately.

I have some data that is in a list of lists of lists.  I would like to apply a function over a subset of each of those (top level) lists, and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with mapping rather than using Table.  In the following example I have three lists of ordered pairs.  I'd like to quickly select a subset of *each* of those three top level lists by testing a property of the deepest level elements.  Doing it for *one* of the three is easy:

```
testList = Table[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {i, 100}], {j, 1, 3}];
subset1 = Select[testList[[1]], PrimeQ[#[[1]]]&];
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not there is some way to do something like this:

```
subsetList = Select[<argument>, PrimeQ[#[[1]]]&] & /@ testList
```

where "argument" is some sort of indicator that it should be mapped "outside" to the testList level.  I'm sure there's some obvious use of Apply or some such that can do this, I just can't quite figure it out!

Comment: I don't know if those are good enough to be duplicates: [16947](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16947/5478), [35322](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35322/5478).

Comment: Why not just `Select[#, PrimeQ[#[[1]]]&] & /@ testList`?

Comment: This works, but I certainly did not think it would until you suggested it.  I guess it's because each "&" denotes a separate rule? If you can help me understand why this works and doesn't confuse the "#"s I'd appreciate it.  I'm accepting a slightly different answer since it seems more general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pure function in the form of `Function[x, ...]` or `Function[{x, y}, ...]` for more arguments. For example,

```
Function[arg, Select[arg, PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &]] /@ testList
```

Comment: This not only works, but is also easily readable and parse-able by my tiny coding brain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using Cases

```
 Cases[#, {x_, y___} /; PrimeQ[x] :> {x, y}] & /@ testList
```

Versification with Map method given by Taiki

```
testList = Table[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {i, 10}], {j, 1, 3}];
Function[arg, Select[arg, PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &]] /@ testList
Cases[#, {x_, y___} /; PrimeQ[x] :> {x, y}] & /@ testList
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate (using `testList` definition given) :

```
c1 = Cases[#, {_?PrimeQ, _}, Infinity] & /@ testList;
c2 = Select[#, PrimeQ[First@#] &] & /@ testList;
c3 = Pick[#, Map[Function[x, PrimeQ[First@x]], #]] & /@ testList;
```

and for the ridiculous:

```
c4 = Flatten[Last[Reap[Sow[{##}, #1], _?PrimeQ, #2[[1]] &]]] /. {} -> 
        Sequence[] & @@@ # & /@ testList;
```

Note:

```
And[c1 == c2, c2 == c3, c3 == c4]
```

yields `True`